# Call Channel From Specific Guild

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My bot is on multiple servers, and I´m trying to setup a member list for each server. The code is supposed to check for a role update (All servers use the same role as a member role) and then post a list of members in a specific channel. Right now the code works up until updatemsg() is called. I get an error saying the guild can't be an integer. How would I fix this error?

```
def updatemsg():
  role = "OfficialMember"
  guild = 754778020639932516
  channel = guild.get_channel(754778311573635213)
  channel.send("\n".join(str(member) for member in role.members))

@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if len(before.roles) < len(after.roles):
        if newRole.name == "OfficialMember":
          print("MemList Updated")
          updatemsg()
        else:
          print("Not OfficialMember Role")
```

Comment: Well yes, an `int` doesn't have any method called `get_channel`. You know how to get a channel, use the same logic to get the guild :)

Comment: Ok, so would I call the guild in the event and pass it on or call it in updatemsg?

Comment: You can use [`Client.get_guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.get_guild), or if you only need the channel, you can simply use [`Client.get_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel)

Comment: Also you need to make `updatemsg` as an `async` and use `await` on the channel operations.

Comment: Of course, I don't know how I missed that.